# Question about the relationships between different areas of mathematics

Tags: algebraic-topology, soft-question, category-theory, representation-theory

I've recently come across the subject of Representation theory, and a Wikipedia search has "representation theory...reduced problems in abstract algebra to linear algebra".  I'm currently learning  algebraic topology, which I've come to the understanding reduces problems in topology to problems in abstract algebra.

My question is:  is there a particular subject matter that reduces problems in topology to problems in linear algebra?

And to generalize this idea:  Is there an area of mathematics that studies reducing problems in (Subject A) to problems in (Subject B)?

Comment: There's always .... cohomology!

Comment: Yes, theoretical physics studies reducing problems in physics (Subject A) to problems in mathematics (Subject B):)

Comment: "*Is there an area of mathematics that studies reducing problems in (Subject A) to problems in (Subject B)?*" I believe this is what functors are for in category theory. There's the fundamental group functor, the higher homotopy group functors, the homology functors, and many more.

Answer (score 3):

You might regard **categories** as **areas of discourse** (like *linear spaces* and *linear homomorphisms*, *groups* and *group homomorphisms*, *topological spaces* and *continuous maps* etc.).

**Functors** are then connecting (in general) different areas of discourse, e.g. to translate problems in one area into problems in another area of discourse (that is possibly better understood).

E.g.

**Galois theory** defines a translation of field extensions into (better understood) group extensions.

**Homology** and **homotopy theory** both define functors from topological spaces (and continuous maps) to groups (and group homomorphisms).

**Algebraic geometry** defines (contravariant) functors establishing a correspondence between algebraic varieties (and inclusion) to ideals of polynomial rings (and inclusion).

etc.